# Vector of pointer to union. How to access elements of the union correctly?

Tags: c++, pointers, unions

I have the following union:

```
union uval_t
{
   size_t   _size;
   void*    _pointer;
   uint32_t _tid[2];
};
```

If I now do the following:

```
std::vector<uval_t*> uvalPointerVec;
uvalPointerVec.push_back((uval_t*)malloc(sizeof(uval_t) * 1000));
```

How do I access the array in the union correctly? Let's say my first union value is of type `size_t`. I can do:

```
uvalPointerVec[0]->_size = 1000;
```

But what are the best practices to do pointer arithmetic with the union pointer to access the elemets?

Example: Can I do the following to access the first union pointer in my vector and access the location after where my `_size` was was stored?

```
uvalPointerVec[0][1]->_tid[0]  = 42;
uvalPointerVec[0][1]->_tid[1]  = 24;
uvalPointerVec[0][2]->_pointer = somePointer;
```

Do I get the following result with this?

```
| 1000 | 42 | 24 | 0x... |
^   ^
|   |_First union value
|_union pointer
```

**Edit:** I think my question is answered (did not try it yet) but a little bit more context for all the confused. I implement the physical algebra of an database system. The Scan operator for example reads data stored in memory and saves all tuples in some kind of data structure. Currently the Scan operator is implemented as template and must work for different page layouts (row store [nsm=n-ary store model] vs column store[pax=partition attributes across]). The data structure which stores the retrieved tuples must work for both page layouts aswell. In NSM (e.g., row-stores) I can access a tuple by a single pointer to that tuple since all attributes are stored in a consecutive manner. For the other page layout I need two integers to exactly adress a tuple: a page number and a record number on that page (tid). Size is needed for some optimization reasons I dont want to discuss now. So if I now want to Scan a NSM page I can store pointer to tuples in my data structure, if i Scan a PAX-page I can reuse the same data structure and instead of storing pointers I store pairs of PageNo/TupleNo.

That is the short version of what I want to achieve

Comment: "But what are the best practices"
Never use unions anywhere

Comment: The best practice for doing pointer arithmetic is to stay far away. Same for unions.

Comment: If you would at least reason about your comments. I need the union, if you like Unions or not was Not the question. This is just a minimal example which shows my problem and I could aswell just try if my idea works But this is Not possible atm and thats why I ask here. No reason to start the Old discussion dont use this of that.

Comment: sure, you can do that. but I'm not sure how you can read from your union without an identifier to know which field to read from.

Comment: May I ask why a size has to be equal to a void pointer? I am really *really* not sure why you use a union here. I smell a X-Y-problem here.

Comment: Deleted my answer again. I still don't quite grasp what you want to achieve here - how would the second index know it's offset without haven given a size? Void has no size. Still recommending that you give some context.

Comment: @Aziuth in my program I dont use a void*. I just used it to say "what ever pointer". Actually i use a byte* and byte is defined as uint8_t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way would be like this:

```
vector[i][j].member = value;
```

Where *i* is the index to your vector element and *j* being an index into the array element *i*.

This is irrelevant to the question but you're using a lot of C rather than C++, I'd suggest replacing your

```
(uval_t*)malloc(sizeof(uval_t) * 1000)
```

With the more standard (but still not desireable):

```
new uval_t[1000]
```

or an even better and more acceptable:

```
std::array<uval_t, 1000>() //fixed size
std::vector<uval_t>(1000) //resizable
```

They are safer and way easier to pass around, they also free themselves when elements are replaced or erased. Array will have equivalent performance and vector coming in close if you make sure to allocate the amount you need beforehand.

Comment: Don't write `new uval_t[1000]`. Don't write `new` at all. The array & vector examples are good.

Comment: ... I'm not really sure any more what the OP intended or didn't intend to do, though. Maybe they are trying to hand-craft a 2D container?

Comment: I can't even imagine what he's doing, it's so bizarre.

Comment: @N.Weber _"Performance is key. I need to use Dynamic Memory allocation no matter what."_ This is a complete non sequitur.

Comment: @N.Weber _"The Common opinion to Never use malloc/new is just Not always possible in practice"_ You misunderstood. You should not use `malloc` or `new`, because you should use library functions that do so for you. That does not reduce performance. The performance is the same, but the maintainability and provable correctness of your code increases. Furthermore, if you _were_ to remove all dynamic allocation from your code (be it manual or otherwise) your performance potentially _would_ increase (though it depends what your replacement approach looks like).